# More parameter than expected: no error in PHP?

Tags: php, runtime-error

Please see this code, where I pass more parameters than expected to a custom function:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

daidai("asassa", "asgfasfas", "asassa");

function daidai($aa)
{
    echo $aa;
}
```

This doesn't emit an error at all, while I was expecting `Warning: function daidai() expects at most 1 parameter, 3 given`

What puzzles me is that this emits said error as expected:

```
$Odate=new DateTime();
$sfasfasf=$Odate->setTime("23", "59", "30", "unexpected");
```

Why?

Comment: Variable number of arguments: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-177

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the `setTime()` method itself performs a check on the number of parameters, if you want it in your functions, you have to implement it yourself.

For reference you might look into [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) for [`func_num_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php), [`func_get_arg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php) and [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

From the docs:

> No special syntax is required to note that a function is variadic;
>   however access to the function's arguments must use func_num_args(),
>   func_get_arg() and func_get_args().

Hence, php really treats every function as a variadic one.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please add a reference to support this?

Comment: I already did by linking the docs, see also the quote I added.