# PHP calling constructors with more arguments than specified

Tags: php, constructor

I was circling around some error in a piece of code in PHP 5.6 and finally found that the error was caused by an outdated call to a constructor of a class. Here, I attempted to pass 3 arguments to a constructor that only expected 2 parameters.

Still, no warning, error, or notice was shown.

Bug or feature?

The following code shouldn't work AT ALL from my understanding, yet it doesn't even cause hickups:

```
<?php

class x {
    function __construct($a) {
    }
}

$y = new x(1, 2);

?>
```

Is there a way to enforce matching parameter counts?

Comment: you might want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188454/more-parameter-than-expected-no-error-in-php)

Comment: Even if you did pass 3 arguments to a function that expects 2, that can't cause the issue since the unused argument is.. unused. Are you sure there isn't anything else going on?

Comment: php is way too lazy, it works as intended more like a design feature than a bug, use a different language if you want to be more strict

Comment: @Mjh I would agree. (In trying to reason the behaviour I would guess that when the constructor _changed_ from 3 to 2 parameters, the nature of these parameters also changed, so the "outdated" call was perhaps just passing the _wrong_ arguments?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with any other function, you can pass an arbitrary number of parameters (as long as you pass the minimum necessary), to enable variable-length argument lists via [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/func_get_args). Feature, not bug.